# Microsft Graph API as WEB API application

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am banging my head for sometime now. I want to develop Web API which will be consume in my Angular APP. Purpose of API is to create/delete Microsoft Teams using Graph API.

I do have azure app with appropriate permission. and below is my code which keep giving me 403 error.

Can someone please help me ? also, do i have to apply permission to below option to access Grpah API without user interaction (as in Login Popup)

[image]

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
               .Create("d78eaba6-12fe-8139")
               .WithTenantId("fd49ee20-51a4-d930e2db05de")
               .WithClientSecret("WTeN7A7-oeOfi~c9gF..")
               .Build();

            var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            var authResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
            string token = authResult.AccessToken;

 await CallWebApiAndProcessResultASync("GET","https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users", token, null, Display);

public static async Task CallWebApiAndProcessResultASync(string method,string webApiUrl, string accessToken, StringContent postValue, Action<JObject> processResult)
        {
            string request = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            {
                using (HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var defaultRequestHeaders = HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;
                    if (defaultRequestHeaders.Accept == null || !defaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Any(m => m.MediaType == "application/json"))
                    {
                        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    }
                    defaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                    using (HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(method), webApiUrl) { Content = postValue })
                    {
                        var response = HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            JObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JObject;
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                            processResult(result);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to call the Web Api: {response.StatusCode}");
                            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                            // Note that if you got reponse.Code == 403 and reponse.content.code == "Authorization_RequestDenied"
                            // this is because the tenant admin as not granted consent for the application to call the Web API
                            Console.WriteLine($"Content: {content}");
                        }
                    }


                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you also done admin consent for the permissions in the Azure AD management portal? After adding the application permission, an admin (global admin in this case since it is MS Graph API) needs to consent to them with a button on the API permissions tab.

Comment: You can check if the permissions you added are in the token by taking the access token you get and go to e.g. https://jwt.ms. There should be a "roles" claim with the application permissions that you added.

Comment: Which api are you using?

Comment: Exposing your client_id & secret is not a good practice. However Did you consented the permissions for [Create Team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0)? Can you also check the permission are listed in access token roles? you can check it over jwt.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you don’t need user interaction, you just need to grant **application permissions** for your application, and grant **admin consent** for the permissions you added. If you need to call MS Graph API to [create/delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/team?view=graph-rest-1.0) Microsoft Teams, please grant your application  `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permission.

[image]

Comment: What will happen if my App is being used by other organisation, for example app is created for ABC.com, while accessing by XYZ.com. it will ask for consent. if user approves then what will happen do i also have access to XYZ.com with same access ? or i will have to ask IT of XYZ.com to grant similar access ?

Comment: Is your application a multi-tenant application?

Comment: @Parth   If your application is a single-tenant application, then other organizations will not have the right to access your application. If your application is a multi-tenant application, then it needs to request the consent of the administrator of the XYZ.com tenant. After the administrator consent, It will be added to the XYZ.com tenant as an enterprise application.

However, the permissions granted to it in the ABC.com tenant will not exist. If it needs to access the resources of XYZ.com, it must request the IT of XYZ.com to grant similar access permissions.